# SQLAlchemy: update from_select

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to execute query like

```
UPDATE node
SET node.parent_id = node_node.parent_id,
    node.label = node_node.label
FROM node_node
WHERE node_node.child_id = node_id
```

using SQLAlchemy. I did search the docs, and found only `insert().from_select()`, but no `update().from_select()`. I know I can achieve the same programatically, but I need it to be as fast as possible.

Is it possible? Could you give me an example or link to docs/any clue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that `t_node` is `node` Table instance, while `t_node_node` - `node_node` Table instance, see the statement below.

```
upd = (t_node.update()
        .values(
            parent_id = t_node_node.c.parent_id,
            label = t_node_node.c.label,
            )
        .where(t_node_node.c.child_id == t_node.c.node_id)
        )
```

Read more on [Inserts, Updates and Deletes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#inserts-and-updates) documentation for more information.

Comment: [In particular](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update): "_The WHERE clause can refer to multiple tables. For databases which support this, an UPDATE FROM clause will be generated_"