# update with join - sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I would like to do an update after joining and filtering two tables with SQLAlchemy:

```
TableA.__table__.
update(mysql_limit = 1).
values(md5sum = 'test').
join(TableB, and_(
    TableA.sp_name == TableB.sp_name,
    TableA.gene == TableB.gene)).
where(and_(
   TableA.md5sum == None,
   func.length(TableB.sequence) < maxlen))
```

However, I run into this error:

> AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'join'

I have looked at a number of other SO answers, but none address this issue directly.

Comment: You can't join an `UPDATE` (`(UPDATE foo SET bar = 1) JOIN baz` makes no sense). What's the SQL that you actually want to output?

Comment: Most probably you will need to use sub-query to achieve UPDATE with JOINs.

Comment: I would like to see how to get sqlalchemy to generate a proper update from join query, but a simple solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030321/sqlalchemy-update-from-select