# Python SqlAlchemy update from select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-update

I searched a lot on google but i can't find anything about it.
How can I translate this query (UPDATE FROM SELECT) into the SqlAlchemy update?

```
                          update tableA 
                           set "column" = tableX.column3
                          from (
                          select a.column1,
                                 a.column2,
                                 a.column3,
                                 case when b.column4 != 0 then
                                    a.column4 / b.column4
                                    else 0
                                 end as "newColumn"
                                 from tableA
                                 inner join tableB b
                                    on a."column1" = b."column2"
                                 where a."column5"='1'                              
                                 ) as tableX
                         where tableA."column1" = tableX."column1"
```

Comment: Is the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030321/sqlalchemy-update-from-select) what you want?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you, but unfortunately no. I tried to adapt this code-snippet but my query is more complex (join, case, multiple, where conditions...)